# How do I prevent my Retina-generated screenshots of Notebooks from being too large?

Tags: support

When I upload a screenshot I've taken of a Mathematica Notebook on my Retina MacBook Pro, the resulting image is HUGE. How can I prevent this and get images that appear at a reasonable size? Can I get images that are scaled appropriately for Retina and non-Retina machines (currently all SE images on my machine are "blurry").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I can recommend:

1. Do not take a screenshot.  Instead, select the graphics, right click, then choose Save As ... and save it as PNG.  This will give you a standard (non-retina) resolution version.  It will have a reasonable size, but it will look blurry on a retina screen.
2. If you would like to include a retina-resolution figure, but display it at standard size (not double size), you can do this: take a screenshot using Command-Shift-4.  When you take the screenshot, OS X will display the width of the region you are clipping.  Remember this number.

   Next, upload the double-size image as usual.  Get the image URL from the end of the post where it gets inserted, and delete the line that looks like `![enter image description here][1]`.  Instead, write `<img src="url" width="360">`  where `url` should be replaced by the actual image URL and `360` should be replaced by the width you noted earlier.

No. 2. from above is what I usually do.  Take a look for example at the MarkDown source of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43761/12).

---

**Update:** I posted [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225199/164803) on Meta StackOverflow to make it easier to include high resolution images.

Comment: Excellent! 2 is the way to go! (I wish that were automatic though, so everyone's posts looked not-like-crap.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I posted a request on MSO to automate this (see update).  Originally I asked in the MSO chatroom if anyone has made a userscript that automates this, then it was suggested to post a feature request ...